# Necessary and Sufficient Condition for Vector Space

Tags: vector-spaces

**Problem** Assume a finite set $F$, write the necessary and sufficient condition in terms of the number of elements of $F$, such that $F$ is a real vector space. (Assuming that the vector addition and scalar multiplication can be defined)

**Attempt at Solution**
Since the necessary conditions for being a vector space is to satisfy the 8 axioms, I thought that $F$ will require at least 3 elements, an identity element, an arbitrary element and the inverse of it.

How could I go from here?

Comment: If $F$ is a real vector space and $F$ has a nonzero vector $v$ , then how many elements are in $span\{v\} = \{ r \cdot v : r \in \mathbb{R}\}$?

Comment: @Joel I'm sorry, I don't understand the $span$ part, can you tell me what it does?

Comment: The span of a single vector is the collection of all scalar multiples of a vector.  That is for each real number $r$, we say that the new vector $r \cdot v$ is in the span of the vector $v$.

Comment: @Joel Thanks, so it implies that a vector space with a nonzero vector necessarily has infinitely many elements?

Comment: Yep!  In fact it would have uncountably many elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a real vector space of positive dimension necessarily contains infinitely many elements, $F$ must be the zero vector space. This suggests that it is necessary and sufficient that $F$ be a singleton set.

Depending on the intention of the problem, there's probably still a couple things to be proven regarding the operations of addition and scalar multiplication, namely that there is only one binary operation on a singleton set (which gives addition), and there is only one possible map $\mathbb R \times F \to F$ giving scalar multiplication.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, why does a real vector space of positive dimension necessarily contains infinitely many elements?

Comment: Suppose $0 \neq v \in F$. Then the claim is that for $r_1, r_2 \in \mathbb R$, $r_1 v = r_2 v$ if and only if $r_1 = r_2$. This isn't actually immediate from the axioms, but it's a standard fact, and probably worth making a stab at proving yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've learned from the comments and it seems I still have a lot to learn about the basics of vector space.